# How "intelligent" is the PDF (ISO) standard: Capable of detecting a BW-printer and adapting accordingly?

Tags: colors, pdf, printing

With [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/165461/setting-color-latex-generated-pdf-to-print-in-black-white) (of 2010) as a starting point, is there a way to **generate a colourful PDF file** (*via* `*TeX`) **such that** it would always be **printed** in **black**-and-**white**, *iff* the printer can't print colours (a black-and-white printer)?

In other words: How *"intelligent"* is the PDF (ISO) standard?

See [ISO_32000-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_32000-1) and [also here](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/acrobat/iso-pdf-x-32000-standards.html).

---

**Edit**

The upshot of this "exercise" is *not* for printing on your own office or home printer, but when you dispatch/publish/release a document and don't know how others on their (unknown) printers will print your carefully crafted document.

Comment: Maybe if someone can answer to this question can also answer to this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121420/elements-that-looks-different-when-printed-with-colours-or-in-bw

Comment: If you know a PDF document with this feature, give us the link. Otherwise, your question is probably off topic in this Q/A site about TeX.

Comment: Maybe worth migrating to `stackoverflow` *et al.* ?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: Already flagged.

Comment: This question should be migrated to stackoverflow (can't write this with off topic reason two)

Comment: Related amazing answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9973/27721

Comment: From the top of my head I do not remember any section of the PDF format that allows device-dependent settings of any kind. The only workaround I can think of is for you to put the B/W content and the color content in two different PDF layers and allow the user to choose which one to use before printing.

Comment: @yms Sounds credible ;) though I guess the standard could still evolve in the future. Regarding different PDF layers and letting the user choose: The fanciest *.pdf I know of has some "dynamic" content (content that changes/is replaced by other content when clicked). Do you happen to have any examples handy which showcase the feature you describe?

Answer (score 4):

PDF is a format of document. So it may not be "intelligent". The PDF standard can not include two different versions of the document (one for color printing and one for printing in black and white).

Comment: Given that on CTAN there are a number of doc's with "dynamic" content (content which is responsive to and changes upon mouse clicks), I somehow doubt that the PDF standard (which is still evolving further) is so limited, that "intelligence" is technically impossible...

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty I know these documents with "dynamic" content. Have you tried to print them?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty The result depends of your PDF viewer.